# Can't open file on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file

For a web app in asp.net, I have to open a file located in my "app_data" directory.
Locally, it works fine.

But when published on the server, I have an error that say : "The system cannot find the file specified"

Here is my code :

```
StreamReader reader = new streamReader(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/pubkey.pem"));
```

Of course, the file exists on the server.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks ;)

EDIT : 
Since the error was not where I think she was, my problem is solved. I have marked mike's response as valid because it helped me a lot to find out I was wrong :)

Comment: try without the ~, if that doesn't work then check where you are actually calling this, maybe you need to add ../../ but I doubt that since it is working locally, I know App_Data is a protected folder so maybe this is somehow blocking you, when publishing make sure to include the App-Data folder

Comment: is that file actually there?

Comment: Did you on server add App_Data as a Virtual folder on IIS? Looks to me like that's the issue. Go to IIS->[Your web app] expand and check if folder is there. If it isn't just right click -> Add Virtual Directory and add path to the folder

Comment: For @CularBytes thanks but same without the ~and the appdata folder is included.

Comment: @DanielA.White yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a App_Data folder defined as a virtual folder in IIS, or a folder in your website project called App_Data, as the ~ says go to the root of website. If your looking for the App_Data folder present in a user profile in windows then it's the virtual folder problem,  or/and giving the app pool identity the proper permissions to access the folder.

```
try
        {   // Open the text file using a stream reader.
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/pubkey.pem")))
            {
            // Read the stream to a string, and write the string to the console.
                string doc = sr.ReadToEnd();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(doc);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Ok thank you but I can't define a virtual folder since my web app is hosted on a 1&1 windows unlimited hosting I have no control over IIS... I tried to put my file on the root of the website but same.
I don't know if it can help but I spied the Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/pubkey.pem") and the value is : E:\kunden\homepages\27\d732552085\www\App_Data\pubkey.pem
I have checked the security settings of this folder and the IUSR has read access

Comment: What do you get when you do this: bool exists =System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/pubkey.pem"));

Comment: I got true... :/

Comment: Ok i added another test to my original answer, see what happens when you run it. If that fails , maybe the exception will tell you whats going on. Since the previous test came back true. It is not a locating/access issue.

Comment: Try right clicking on the file(not the App_Data folder), select properties, then look at the properties window and check the Build Action, should be set to Content. Also gives you the option on when to Copy to Output Directory. (ie if its newer then deployed version)

Comment: Oh, i'm so sorry, the error was not on this line but few lines later. I thought it was on this line because of the error message : "cannot find the file" I'm sorry and you was very helpful for me to find than the error was not located where I thought
Thank you :D